# ionic5 issue: "index.js:7 Error: Invalid value type at Function.a.set"

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

Those two errors appear every time I run any ionic project; they appear on all browsers that I have tried like Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge… etc.

I also tried to run old projects that were running fine, and the same errors show now!

```
Error: Invalid value type
    at Function.a.set (index.js:7)
    at t.setIsTrutedEnforced (index.js:7)
    at index.js:49
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Given action "NormalMode/SetPageData", reducer "isTrustedEnforced" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.
    at index.js:7
    at Object.g [as dispatch] (index.js:7)
    at t.SetPageData (index.js:7)
    at index.js:49
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your post this time, but [please do not use images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8289918). It makes it harder for others to help you. Also, please include a [mcve] and read the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are thrown by the Kaspersky Password Manager extension script (at least it was the source in my case).
If you disable that extension, errors will stop showing up.

Comment: I disable the extension and errors disappear! thank you so much